# Spring @PostMapping not pre-pending Controller classes Path

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

i am on spring-boot **'2.0.2.RELEASE'** and found a strange issue. I have my controller class annotated as `@RestController("/user")`, and one of the method annotated as `@PostMapping("/random")`. So the request mappings for the APIs should look like `"/{server-context}/user/random"` . However, the mappings are being configured as `"/{server-context}/random"` . I guess spring boot is not respecting the Class level path mappings. Is this a bug? or am i missing something here. Spring boot 1.5.x didnt had such behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value in RestController is for spring bean discovery, it does not indicate the root path for the controller.

Use this instead:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class Class ...
```

Comment: sorry my bad, just slipped my head.